# Why my LLVM instructions are not added? (missing in compiled binary)

Tags: clang, llvm, clang++, llvm-c++-api

I'm trying to learn the LLVM functionality and I think I'm missing something. I've a sample modulepass, right now i'm trying to add two sample instructions to basic block (they don't have much sense but it's just for testing whether it works or not). Everything seems to run correctly, but the resulting binary contains no added instructions (are they removed by dead code eliminator or something ??)

```
// compilation: clang.exe -mwindows tiny.c -o tiny.exe
for (BasicBlock& bb : F)
{
    for (BasicBlock::iterator it = bb.begin(), it_end = bb.end(); it != it_end; ++it)
    {
        if (!it->isBinaryOp())
            continue;

        // executed at. ie. %add = add i32 %call, 1
        // mul i32 %call, 10
    
        // add some instructions
        Value* op1 = BinaryOperator::CreateNeg(iter_bb->getOperand(0), "neg", &*it);
                Value *op2 = BinaryOperator::Create(Instruction::Add, op1, iter_bb->getOperand(1),"cre",&*it);
    }
}
```

Code compiles ok but the binary contains no added instructions :(

Comment: Those might well get eliminated by DCE. Try `clang -mllvm -print-after-all` to print the IR after each pass to see whether they're added and when they're removed.

Comment: that may be it since, if I later use the op2 it gets emitted to the final code. Anyway do you have any idea why when opcode==ICmp and i try to change the predicate ICmpInst *c = (ICmpInst *)(&it); c->setPredicate(ICmpInst::ICMP_SLE); it doesn't change